# help with selecting rows using awk

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I have a file as follows

- 2.54 Ghz   val
- 2.53 Ghz   val1
- 1.6 Ghz     val2
- 800 Mhz     val3
- 2.54 Ghz    val4
- 2.53 Ghz    val5
- 1.6 Ghz    val6
- 800 Mhz     val7

and the pattern continues ...
I want to extract all 2.54 Ghz values in one file1 and all 2.53 Ghz values in another file2
, 1.60 Ghz values in file3 and 800 Mhz values in file4

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 awk '{print $0 > "file_"$1"_"$2}' file
```

Comment: Or possibly `...print $3 > ...` if only you only want the values and not the full line.

Comment: yes, if OP only wants the values. I will leave it as $0 for the sake of generality.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
rm --force file_*

while read speed magnitude value; do
    echo -e "${value}" >> "file_${speed}_${magnitude}"
done < file
```